# Hibernate delete doesn't cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a few entities linked as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distribution_activity")
public class DistributionActivity extends AbstractActivity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "activity", orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<DistributionTask> tasks = new TreeSet<>();

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distribution_task")
public class DistributionTask extends AbstractTask {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id")
    protected DistributionActivity activity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
    protected Store store;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "store", orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<DistributionTask> distributionTasks = new TreeSet<>();

    ...
}
```

The repositories are as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface DistributionActivityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DistributionActivity, Long> {
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface StoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Store, Long> {
}
```

I'm using MySQL and the tables are generated WITHOUT any cascade options on the foreign keys. When I delete a DistributionActivity everything works fine and Hibernate actually issues delete statements for each of the linked tasks.

```
hibernate.SQL:109 - delete from distribution_task where id=? and version=?
hibernate.SQL:109 - delete from distribution_activity where id=? and version=?
```

When I delete a Store however, no delete statements are generated for the linked tasks and a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException exception is thrown referring to a foreign key violation.

```
hibernate.SQL:109 - delete from store where id=? and version=?
```

Any clues?

Comment: Check which fk is being violated, verify if there is something else that depends on that fk. Your code looks fine to me, maybe there is an extra dependency not shown in your snippets.

Comment: Thanks Yori, the exception is thrown from the FK between DistributionTask and Store. Message: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sm`.`distribution_task`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dr8qheutxond3mpexbuvm6s9f` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`))

Comment: How do you generate your tables? If you generate with Hibernate Schema; then I would suggest dropping all tables and regenerate your schema.

Comment: Yes, using Hibernate schema. I already tried dropping the DB and regenerating .. Same issue.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code where you successfully delete a  DistributionActivity and try to delete a Store right after it (the point where the exception is thrown)?

Comment: I added the repository code. I delete a DistributionActivity using the repo.delete() method, pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the snippet of code around session.delete() where the deletion happens?

I cannot say it for sure but I have ran in similar issues before related to bidirectional relationships. Briefly speaking, I needed to make sure the objects are in sync when using bidirectional relationships.

It looks to me that you want to delete a Store that still have a reference in DistributionTask.

Example, if you have something like this:

```
session.delete(store);
```

Then, try changing for something like this:

```
distributionTask.setStore(null);
session.save(distributionTask);
session.delete(store);
```

So; you need control the consistency of your objects manually when dealing with bidirectional relationship.

I hope it helps. Cheers,

Comment: I understand, but how is the DistributionActivity delete operation working smoothly without any manual work?