# OneToMany relationship orphans are not removed from the DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Originally this problem/bug posted on Hibernate's JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12311

My log properties are set to:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.event.internal: TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry: TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.spi: TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.internal: TRACE
```

I have two entities: `Job` and `Step`
Job has a oneToMany relationship with Step which is marked with `orphanRemoval = True`.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "JOB_STEP")
private List<Step> steps;
```

Expected behavior is when a certain step is removed from `steps` list, `DELETE` queries should be executed on `STEP` and `JOB_STEP` tables.

---

First case, the expected behavior occurs when following code is executed:

```
Job job = new Job("Test");
Step step = new Step("Test");
job.addStep(step);
repository.save(job);
job.removeStep(step);
repository.save(job);
```

I see three expected log messages:

```
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener: Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 1 deletions to 2 objects
org.hibernate.SQL: delete from job_step where job_id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: delete from step where id=?
```

---

Second case, when `orphanRemoval = true` doesn't invoke the deletion of orphans from the DB.

```
Job job = new Job("Test");
Step step = new Step("Test");
repository.save(job); //This causes the bug to happen
job.addStep(step);
repository.save(job);
job.removeStep(step);
repository.save(job);
```

After the above code is executed, I can still see entries in STEP and JOB_STEP tables in the DB.

Following log is printed: `Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects`

---

I've been trying to find the root cause of this problem for few weeks now through debugging the Hibernate's source code. But it didn't really help. However, I noticed few abnormal things that might be helpful for you:

1) During debugging, I stumbled upon this method `resetStoredSnapshot` from `org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry` that essentially just wipes the stored snapshot of Steps that later on causes Hibernate not to find orphans. While in the first case, when Hibernate works as expected, `resetStoredSnapshot` is not executed at all.

2) I noticed that java.util.List of Steps starts working aberrantly once it gets converted to org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList by Hibernate

---

The workspace with reproduced bug is here: https://github.com/yeralin/ReproduceBug

Comment: for a 50 pt bounty, I will have a look. Basically, you want it to execute deletes for the case you outline or explain why it can't/isn't done?

Comment: I had a similar question a while back but never got to the root cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487796/hibernate-delete-doesnt-cascade

Comment: the children must be removed while the entity is managed, if you remove the children outside the persistence context (in client for example / front end or so) , then you tried to save the parent with the newly removed children , the children wont be removed ... so I don't know if `job.removeStep(step);` is inside the Persistence context or nor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the doc on save](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-):

`Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.`

You should do this:

```
job = repository.save(job);
```

`step` may also be different after the save.

To remember this, think about the `@Id`. When you save an entity, you get potentially a new object with an updated id. Same with the children like `step`.

Comment: This is so not obvious, all tutorials I followed didn't really highlight this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know why you have separate table for **`OnToMany`** relationship.You can implement **One To Many** relationship with `jobID` as one column inside `steps` table.

To implement **`OnToMany`** relationship properly please follow https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/.

Now to answer your question:

To remove orphan you need to set its parent to **null**, if you have **Bi-Directional** relationship
Something like

```
job.removeStep(step);
step.setJob(null);
```

Also have a look at this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071125/3425489